# How to make a POST query for multi city flight offers search with Amadeus Ruby gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, post, amadeus

I am trying to test out the flight offers search API for multi city flight searches.

I am using the amadeus gem. see: https://github.com/amadeus4dev/amadeus-ruby
I am using Rails 6.

I have the following in a controller action

```
def flight_offer_results
  destinations = {
    "originDestinations" => [
      {
        "id" => 1,
        "originLocationCode" => "LON",
        "destinationLocationCode" => "NYC",
        "departureDateTimeRange" => {
          "date" => "2020-12-30"
        }
      },
      {
        "id" => 2,
        "originLocationCode" => "IAH",
        "destinationLocationCode" => "SFO",
        "departureDateTimeRange" => {
          "date" => "2021-01-15"
        }
      }
    ],
    "travelers" => [
      {
        "id" => 1,
        "travelerType" => "ADULT"
      }
    ],
    "sources" => [ 
      "GDS"
    ],
    "searchCriteria" => {
      "maxFlightOffers" => 1
    }
  }

  begin
    amadeus = Amadeus::Client.new
    response = amadeus.shopping.flight_offers_search.post(destinations)
    @flight_offers = response.data
    puts "@flight_offers =========>>>>>>>> #{@flight_offers}"
  rescue Amadeus::ResponseError => e
    raise e
  end
end
```

When I run this code I get the following error in the console:

```
Amadeus::NetworkError ([---]):
```

I can make a get request and return results for one origin and destination.

How can I make the POST request to be able to query for multi city flight searches?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the code above is not propper json. So, I added `.to_json` to destinations in the line that performs the post request and it worked.

```
response = amadeus.shopping.flight_offers_search.post(destinations.to_json)
```